# No puedo hacer ping a un contenedor docker

Tags: windows, docker

estoy corriendo docker sobre windows 10; tengo configurado dos contenedores sobre los cuales no puedo hacer ping:

```
> docker inspect -f "{{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress}}" app_nginx
172.17.0.3

Al hacer ping, sale tiempo de espera agotado.
Al hacer ipconfig:

    Adaptador de Ethernet vEthernet (DockerNAT):

       Sufijo DNS específico para la conexión. . :
       Vínculo: dirección IPv6 local. . . : 
       Dirección IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.75.1
       Máscara de subred . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
       Puerta de enlace predeterminada . . . . . :

    Adaptador de LAN inalámbrica Conexión de área local* 10:

       Estado de los medios. . . . . . . . . . . : medios desconectados
       Sufijo DNS específico para la conexión. . :

    Adaptador de LAN inalámbrica Wi-Fi:

       Sufijo DNS específico para la conexión. . : xxxxxx
       Vínculo: dirección IPv6 local. . . : _::_:_:_:4f10%3
       Dirección IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.15
       Máscara de subred . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
       Puerta de enlace predeterminada . . . . . : 192.168.0.1

    Adaptador de túnel xxxxxxx:

       Estado de los medios. . . . . . . . . . . : medios desconectados
       Sufijo DNS específico para la conexión. . : xxxxxxx

    Adaptador de túnel yyyyyyy:

       Estado de los medios. . . . . . . . . . . : medios desconectados
       Sufijo DNS específico para la conexión. . :

Al revisar la informacion de bridge:
 docker network inspect bridge
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "734d974df1d9d113d2b7eb25564ea6933f02e07f199683f21c5bb7eb51b4421d",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Containers": {
            "207c9c31bc0d75170010ecc9abb0ea0833529ceeff414775a4771b539d32751e": {
                "Name": "app_php",
                "EndpointID": "1a2876ce257f714b63e65bc134419839da94a5edb3802c5b3a06757857447e5f",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "ca51d37feb4d5b10946ee44f41432f41506b0cfb217e4e0ee820e69fd9260305": {
                "Name": "app_nginx",
                "EndpointID": "33be98be3d5234a821160ecc86ca7abce3ea764ad31b4a979d27d56abb8d0992",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

En resumen tengo como ip del Getway bridge 172.17.0.1, el container que me interesa 172.17.0.3 y si reviso la ip en docker nat en windows es 10.0.75.1

Probé redirigiendo todo lo de 172.17.0.x por 10.0.75.1, pero no me ha funcionado.

> route add 172.0.0.0/16 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.0.75.1
>   obteniendo como resultado al hacer ping. Tiempo de espera agotado.

Se que en última instancia puedo exponer un puerto de manera local, sin embargo quisiera saber porque no es posible acceder de esta forma.
Gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 4):

En mi opinión no tiene mucho sentido hacer ping a un contendor.
Si tienes cientos de contenedores es una locura estar averiguando su ip interna para hacerles ping.

Supongo que hacer un ping al contenedor es para revisar si esta corriendo correctamente. Para ello es mejor utilizar las herramientas que te da Docker.

En mi caso si quiero ver si un contenedor esta corriendo ejecuto ***sudo docker ps*** y me muestra una lista con los puertos abiertos y a donde se redirigen, el tiempo que llevan ejecutandose...

```
informatica@Bender:~/Desarrollo/blog/gitlab/blog$ sudo docker ps 

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
9b790cb8563d        asg1612/glpi            "/usr/bin/supervisord"   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:8001->80/tcp               affectionate_murdock
788d335b1b2d        mariadb                 "docker-entrypoint..."   24 hours ago        Up 24 hours         3306/tcp                           mariadb-glpi
e8a143ac0733        minio/minio             "minio server /export"   24 hours ago        Up 24 hours         0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp             minio1
31f6e156c5ac        registry:2              "/entrypoint.sh /e..."   24 hours ago        Up 24 hours         0.0.0.0:5001->5000/tcp             sharp_williams
ef4e1d05d588        rancher/server:v1.6.0   "/usr/bin/entry --..."   11 days ago         Up 28 hours         3306/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   sharp_haibt
8b89dc38fb29        mysql                   "docker-entrypoint..."   3 months ago        Up 28 hours         0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp             ranger-mysql
b7e8c47b42d9        registry:2              "/entrypoint.sh /e..."   3 months ago        Up 28 hours         0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp             registry
```

Puede que el contenedor este levantado pero la aplicacion que ejecuta no este funcionando correctamente. Para ello lo reviso con el comando ***sudo docker logs***

```
informatica@Bender:~/Desarrollo/blog/gitlab/blog$ sudo docker logs 9b790cb8563d
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:297: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
  'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
2017-06-13 09:00:13,877 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2017-06-13 09:00:13,877 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf" during parsing
2017-06-13 09:00:13,884 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2017-06-13 09:00:13,885 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2017-06-13 09:00:13,885 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2017-06-13 09:00:14,886 INFO spawned: 'apache' with pid 8
2017-06-13 09:00:14,914 INFO exited: apache (exit status 0; not expected)
2017-06-13 09:00:15,916 INFO spawned: 'apache' with pid 18
2017-06-13 09:00:15,948 INFO exited: apache (exit status 0; not expected)
2017-06-13 09:00:16,949 INFO gave up: apache entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

En caso de que necesite investigar algo mas consigo un shell dentro del contenedor. Lo que me permite cacharrear y hacer mas comprobaciones.

```
informatica@Bender:~/Desarrollo/blog/gitlab/blog$ sudo docker exec -ti 9b790cb8563d /bin/bash
root@9b790cb8563d:/var/local/www#
```

Mas información de los commandos:
- [docker ps](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/)
- [docker logs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/)

Answer (score 2):

No es posible hacer ping a cualquiera de los dos contenedores de esta manera, esto es debido a que se encuentran en una red diferente a la de tu PC físico.

Puedes probar creando una red nueva usando el controlador puente y asignando tú mismo los parámetros de configuración para que sea Docker quien se encargue de establecer las IP dentro del rango aceptado por tu red local:

```
  $ docker network create \
  --driver=bridge \
  --subnet=172.28.0.0/16 \
  --ip-range=172.28.5.0/24 \
  --gateway=172.28.5.254 \
  nombre_de_tu_red_docker
```

No olvides modificar toda la configuración de acuerdo a tu red.

Luego al momento de ejecutar los contenedores, o levantarlos, asegúrate de vincularlos a esa red, por ejemplo:

```
$ docker run -d --net=nombre_de_tu_red_docker -it ubuntu:16.04 bash
```

Luego podrás escanear las IP asignadas a tus contenedores, y si se encuentran en la misma red de tu PC, no deberías tener inconvenientes para hacer ping de un lado a otro. Sino fíjate como funciona VirtualBox, al crear una máquina virtual y asignarle el controlador puente, este se comporta como un nodo más en tu red local, y recibe una IP y demás configuraciones a partir de tu servidor DHCP (módem, router o hub).